# Для десктопных приложений лучше использовать QML или QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, qml

Недавно начал учить Qt Quick Controls 2, и мне безумно понравился его интерфейс, но думаю все-таки красота требует жертв (производительность).
Хочу взять совет у профессионалов, для маленьких/больших проектов лучше использовать QMainWindow или QML?

Comment: Вопрос скорее подразумевает обмен мнениями, нежели объективную реальность. Для себя когда я выбирал технологию для своих проектов, я остановился на гибридном варианте - основа на QWidget, а какие-то отдельные части, требующие нестандартного подхода, или хорошо подходящие под концепцию, на QML. По результатам моих исследований десктопные приложения полностью на QML писать пока рано, технология пока много не может.

Comment: Для больших приложений будет важна скорость разработки форм и оперативность внесения в них изменений. Да и какой же нужно сделать интерфейс, чтобы современные десктопы тормозили? Я за QML )

Answer (score 0):

Давно пишу на QML. Просто, гибко, удобно. Недостающие (платформеннозависимые) возможности, легко дополняются через плюсы.

Но я согласен с комментарием выше, все это вкусовщина.